# Query SQL to get all column and min max datetime by MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, unique

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server. And Here is my table
[image]
**Added sample data format text as table**

```
╒══════════╤═════════════╤══════════╤═══════╤═════════════╤═════════════════════╤══════════════════╤══════════════════════╤══════════╤═════════════╤═════╤════════════╤════════════╤════════════╤══════════╕
│ RecordID │ ID Employee │ Resource │ Shift │ ProjectID   │ Drawing No          │ Production order │ PN                   │ Quantity │ ProductName │ BNo │ Start Date │ Start Time │ End Date   │ End Time │
╞══════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════╡
│ 60431    │ 2088        │ M-JO     │ HC    │ E195256-A01 │ No.31               │ MA-000000001     │ SHAFT-DBT-999M       │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-10-05 │ 13:23:27   │ NULL       │ NULL     │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 8354     │ 2029        │ M-JO     │ HC    │ E183127-A01 │ VPR180714801/603-F2 │ MA-000001FAB     │ VY1200-DISE-700F     │ 7        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-23 │ 09:41:48   │ 2019-09-23 │ 14:38:18 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 8408     │ 2058        │ M-MD2.5  │ 1     │ E183127-A01 │ VPR180714801/603-F2 │ MA-000001FAB     │ VY1200-DISE-700F     │ 7        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-23 │ 15:32:53   │ 2019-09-23 │ 16:51:19 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 50130    │ 2175        │ M-ML1.5  │ HC    │ L190004-A01 │ VS1-0931991         │ MA-000001PHA     │ L190004-A01-051-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-19 │ 15:59:23   │ 2020-05-19 │ 18:06:14 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 50231    │ 2175        │ M-ML1.5  │ HC    │ L190004-A01 │ VS1-0931991         │ MA-000001PHA     │ L190004-A01-051-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-20 │ 08:04:39   │ 2020-05-20 │ 16:53:53 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 50874    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ L190004-A01 │ VS1-1633944-00      │ MA-000002PHA     │ L190004-A01-005-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-22 │ 10:11:08   │ 2020-05-22 │ 16:39:43 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 51030    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ L190004-A01 │ VS1-1633944-00      │ MA-000002PHA     │ L190004-A01-005-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-23 │ 08:06:43   │ 2020-05-23 │ 11:38:03 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 52063    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ E203089-A01 │ VS1-1633944-00      │ MA-000003PHA     │ E203089-A01-005-023C │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-28 │ 13:23:48   │ 2020-05-28 │ 18:29:19 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 52204    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ E203089-A01 │ VS1-1633944-00      │ MA-000003PHA     │ E203089-A01-005-023C │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-29 │ 08:05:22   │ 2020-05-29 │ 12:51:25 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 8051     │ 2163        │ M-MLV1.6 │ 3     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-21 │ 02:30:14   │ 2019-09-21 │ 06:00:00 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 8052     │ 2028        │ M-MLV1.6 │ 1     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-21 │ 08:10:59   │ 2019-09-21 │ 10:00:00 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 8100     │ 2029        │ M-JO     │ 2     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-21 │ 14:05:12   │ 2019-09-21 │ 15:36:38 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 8222     │ 2058        │ M-MD2.5  │ HC    │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-22 │ 11:24:54   │ 2019-09-22 │ 14:43:19 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 15490    │ 2228        │ M-MP3    │ 1     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-26 │ 06:51:06   │ 2019-10-26 │ 14:00:50 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 15585    │ 2226        │ M-MP3    │ 2     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-26 │ 14:03:21   │ 2019-10-26 │ 19:58:07 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 15979    │ 2034        │ M-MD3    │ 1     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-29 │ 09:08:52   │ 2019-10-29 │ 13:17:48 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 16056    │ 2212        │ M-MLV1.4 │ 1     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-29 │ 14:23:47   │ 2019-10-29 │ 17:51:46 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 16136    │ 2087        │ M-MLV1.4 │ 3     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-29 │ 19:08:29   │ 2019-10-30 │ 05:53:22 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 16188    │ 2212        │ M-MLV1.4 │ 1     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-30 │ 06:09:27   │ 2019-10-30 │ 08:22:06 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 16445    │ 2058        │ M-MD2.5  │ 3     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-30 │ 20:59:08   │ 2019-10-30 │ 22:29:19 │
├──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────┤
│ 16456    │ 2087        │ M-MLV1.4 │ 3     │ E183116-A03 │ VP7R810400/021X1    │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-10-31 │ 00:05:14   │ 2019-10-31 │ 03:05:41 │
╘══════════╧═════════════╧══════════╧═══════╧═════════════╧═════════════════════╧══════════════════╧══════════════════════╧══════════╧═════════════╧═════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧══════════╛
```

I tried to get unique `Production order`, Min start date, start time and Max end date and end time like

```
SELECT
        [Production order], MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS DATETIME))   AS MIN_DATE_TIME, MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MAX_DATE_TIME
    FROM
        TIMEDATA1
    WHERE RESOURCE not like 'I-%'
    GROUP BY
        [Production order]
    order by 
        [Production order] ASC
```

[image]

However, There are only `Production order, MIN_DATE_TIME, MAX_DATE_TIME` column. That I can query.
I tried with query

```
   SELECT
   distinct [Production order] ,PN, ProjectID,[Drawing No], MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS DATETIME))   AS MIN_DATE_TIME, MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MAX_DATE_TIME
FROM
    TIMEDATA1
WHERE RESOURCE not like 'I-%'
GROUP BY
    [Production order]
order by 
    [Production order] ASC
```

It showed error like this
[image]

I expect to get more column such as `PN, ProjectID, Drawing No`

Please help me, Thank you so much !

Comment: You have to explicitly select them in your query... Currently, only the mentioned `Production order,` `MIN_DATE_TIME` and `MAX_DATE_TIME` are selected. Add the desired other ones to the `SELECT` clause. And if you want unique values, you maybe want to `SELECT DISTINCT` ones.

Comment: Images of data really don't help us help you. Take the time to post sample data in a consumable format; preferably DDL and DML but if not then tabular formatted `text`.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: You (rarely) never need to do SELECT DISTINCT when you do GROUP BY, because the GROUP BY eliminates duplicates.

Comment: @jarlh Please help clearly or answer Thank you !

Comment: I can't read that tiny image text, so it's hard to assist you. Make it easy to assist you, show us sample table data and expected result as formatted text, not images. And simplify - [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the additional columns in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT [Production order], PN, ProjectID,[ Drawing No],
       MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MIN_DATE_TIME,
       MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MAX_DATE_TIME
FROM TIMEDATA1
WHERE RESOURCE not like 'I-%'
GROUP BY [Production order], PN, ProjectID,[ Drawing No]
ORDER BY [Production order] ASC;
```

All non-aggregated columns should be in the `GROUP BY`.

If this returns multiple rows per production order, that is because the values are different.  You need to specify what you want to do in such a situation.  If this is an issue, I would recommend that you ask a *new* question, providing sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of what to do.  The data should be *text tables* not images.

Comment: Thank for your help and tips. I asked a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64273504/how-to-get-unique-row-all-column-and-min-max-datetime-by-query-on-mssql . Please help

Answer (score 0):

Put your first result in a CTE or subquery and join back to the main table:

;with MinMax as (
SELECT
[Production order], MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS DATETIME))   AS MIN_DATE_TIME, MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MAX_DATE_TIME
FROM
TIMEDATA1
WHERE RESOURCE not like 'I-%'
GROUP BY
[Production order]
order by
[Production order] ASC
)
SELECT TD.*, MM.Min_Date_Time, MM.Max_Date_Time
FROM TIMEDATA1 TD
INNER JOIN MinMax MM on MM.[Production order] = TD.[Production order]

Answer (score 0):

Put your first result in a CTE or subquery and join back to the main table:

```
;with MinMax as (
SELECT
   [Production order], MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS 
DATETIME))   AS MIN_DATE_TIME, MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS 
DATETIME)) AS MAX_DATE_TIME
    FROM
        TIMEDATA1
    WHERE RESOURCE not like 'I-%'
    GROUP BY
        [Production order]
    order by 
        [Production order] ASC
)
SELECT TD.*, MM.Min_Date_Time, MM.Max_Date_Time
FROM TIMEDATA1 TD 
      INNER JOIN MinMax MM on MM.[Production order] = TD.[Production order]
```