# How to get unique row, all column and min max datetime by query on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Query in Microsoft SQL Server

```
select * 
from TIMEDATA1 
order by [Production order] asc
```

I get data like this:

```
╔══════════╤═════════════╤══════════╤═══════╤═════════════╤════════════╤══════════════════╤══════════════════════╤══════════╤═════════════╤═════╤════════════╤════════════╤════════════╤══════════╗
║ RecordID │ ID Employee │ Resource │ Shift │ ProjectID   │ Drawing No │ Production order │ PN                   │ Quantity │ ProductName │ BNo │ Start Date │ Start Time │ End Date   │ End Time ║
╠══════════╪═════════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪════════════╪══════════════════╪══════════════════════╪══════════╪═════════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════╪════════════╪══════════╣
║ 60431    │ 2088        │ M-JO     │ HC    │ E195256-A01 │ 1A         │ MA-000000001     │ SHAFT-DBT-999M       │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-10-05 │ 13:23:27   │ NULL       │ NULL     ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 8354     │ 2029        │ M-JO     │ HC    │ E183127-A01 │ 2A         │ MA-000001FAB     │ VY1200-DISE-700F1    │ 7        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-23 │ 09:41:48   │ 2019-09-23 │ 14:38:18 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 8408     │ 2058        │ M-MD2.5  │ 1     │ E183127-A02 │ 3A         │ MA-000001FAB     │ VY1200-DISE-700F2    │ 7        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-23 │ 15:32:53   │ 2019-09-23 │ 16:51:19 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 50130    │ 2175        │ M-ML1.5  │ HC    │ L190004-A01 │ 4A         │ MA-000001PHA     │ L190004-A01-051-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-19 │ 15:59:23   │ 2020-05-19 │ 18:06:14 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 50231    │ 2175        │ M-ML1.5  │ HC    │ L190004-A02 │ 4B         │ MA-000001PHA     │ L190004-A01-051-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-20 │ 08:04:39   │ 2020-05-20 │ 16:53:53 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 50874    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ L190004-A07 │ 5C         │ MA-000002PHA     │ L190004-A01-005-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-22 │ 10:11:08   │ 2020-05-22 │ 16:39:43 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 51030    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ L190004-A08 │ 5C         │ MA-000002PHA     │ L190004-A01-005-023C │ 2        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-23 │ 08:06:43   │ 2020-05-23 │ 11:38:03 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 52063    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ E203089-A05 │ 2AW        │ MA-000003PHA     │ E203089-A01-005-023C │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-28 │ 13:23:48   │ 2020-05-28 │ 18:29:19 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 52204    │ 2134        │ M-ML2    │ HC    │ E203089-A01 │ 1A         │ MA-000003PHA     │ E203089-A01-005-023C │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2020-05-29 │ 08:05:22   │ 2020-05-29 │ 12:51:25 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 8051     │ 2163        │ M-MLV1.6 │ 3     │ E183116-A03 │ Q          │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M1 │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-21 │ 02:30:14   │ 2019-09-21 │ 06:00:00 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 8052     │ 2028        │ M-MLV1.6 │ 1     │ E183116-A02 │ P          │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-21 │ 08:10:59   │ 2019-09-21 │ 10:00:00 ║
╟──────────┼─────────────┼──────────┼───────┼─────────────┼────────────┼──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼──────────┼─────────────┼─────┼────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────╢
║ 8100     │ 2029        │ M-JO     │ 2     │ E183116-A03 │ X          │ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M  │ 1        │ NULL        │ B01 │ 2019-09-21 │ 14:05:12   │ 2019-09-21 │ 15:36:38 ║
╚══════════╧═════════════╧══════════╧═══════╧═════════════╧════════════╧══════════════════╧══════════════════════╧══════════╧═════════════╧═════╧════════════╧════════════╧════════════╧══════════╝
```

I tried with query

```
SELECT [Production order], PN, ProjectID,[ Drawing No],
       MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MIN_DATE_TIME,
       MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS DATETIME)) AS MAX_DATE_TIME
FROM TIMEDATA1
WHERE RESOURCE not like 'I-%'
GROUP BY [Production order], PN, ProjectID,[ Drawing No]
ORDER BY [Production order] ASC;
```

However It return multiple rows per production order.
I expect to query to have table as

```
╔══════════════════╤══════════════════════╤═════════════╤════════════╤═════════════════════════╤═════════════════════════╗
║ Production order │ PN                   │ ProjectID   │ Drawing No │ MIN_DATE_TIME           │ MAX_DATE_TIME           ║
╠══════════════════╪══════════════════════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═════════════════════════╪═════════════════════════╣
║ MA-000000001     │ SHAFT-DBT-999M       │ E195256-A01 │ 1A         │ 2020-10-05 13:23:27.000 │ NULL                    ║
╟──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║ MA-000001FAB     │ VY1200-DISE-700F1    │ E183127-A01 │ 2A         │ 2019-09-23 09:41:48.000 │ 2019-09-23 16:51:19.000 ║
╟──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║ MA-000001PHA     │ L190004-A01-051-023C │ L190004-A01 │ 4A         │ 2020-05-19 15:59:23.000 │ 2020-05-20 16:53:53.000 ║
╟──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║ MA-000002PHA     │ L190004-A01-005-023C │ L190004-A07 │ 5C         │ 2020-05-22 10:11:08.000 │ 2020-05-23 11:38:03.000 ║
╟──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║ MA-000003PHA     │ E203089-A01-005-023C │ E203089-A01 │ 2AW        │ 2020-05-28 13:23:48.000 │ 2020-05-29 12:51:25.000 ║
╟──────────────────┼──────────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────┼─────────────────────────╢
║ MA-000005198     │ VY0750031-SUCB-819M1 │ E183116-A03 │ Q          │ 2019-09-21 02:30:14.000 │ 2019-10-21 15:36:38.000 ║
╚══════════════════╧══════════════════════╧═════════════╧════════════╧═════════════════════════╧═════════════════════════╝
```

**Note**: `Production order` should be unique value. `PN, ProjectID, Drawing No` should be unique value also .That can get from  first row or any.

`MIN_DATE_TIME` is `MIN( CAST([Start Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([Start Time] AS DATETIME))`

`MAX_DATE_TIME` is `MAX(CAST([End Date] AS DATETIME) + CAST([End Time] AS DATETIME))`

I had a question similar like this from [Query SQL to get all column and min max datetime by MSSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64258274/query-sql-to-get-all-column-and-min-max-datetime-by-mssql/64261716#64261716)

I try with result of answer however @Gordon Linoff mentioned this returns multiple rows per production order, that is because the values are different
Please help me. Thank you !

**EDIT**

Data type

Start Date: date

End Date: date

Start Time: time(0)

End Time: time(0)

I know this report is poor report design. But I make it for other purpose

Comment: Your table clearly has duplicate values for the production order column. What determines a unique value ?

Comment: What is the data type for the start_date/start_time and end_date/end_time columns?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn data type for start_date/start_time columns  are date/time(0). end_date/end_time columns are date/time(0) also

Answer (score 1):

I need to know the data type for your date and time columns to know the best way to finish the last two columns. Since that's not in the question, here's the rest of it, which is enough to get you started:

```sql
select [Production order]
   , MIN(PN) as PN
   , MIN(ProjectID) as ProjectID
   , MIN([Drawing No]) as [Drawing No]
from TIMEDATA1 
group by [Production order]
order by [Production order] asc
```

---

I also noticed this:

> PN, ProjectID, Drawing No should be unique value also .That can get from first row or any.

This is also a common requirement, but it's **really poor** report design, because it's very easy to end up showing data that doesn't make sense.

For example, looking at the sample result data we see these values for production order, drawing, and end time:

```
MA-000001FAB, 2A, 2019-09-23 16:51:19.000
```

However, looking at the original data for drawing `2A` we can see this end time is not associated with that drawing. In other words, this is data that doesn't make any sense to show side-by-side. *It's your job to know this and either push back against that kind of requirement or understand how to expand it to show the correct row.*

If you *must* settle for this poor requirement, it's better to do something like this:

```sql
select *
from (
    select [Production order], PN, ProjectID, [Drawing No]
        , row_number() over (partition by [production order] order by [production order], end_date, end_time) as rn
    from TIMEDATA1 
) t1
where rn = 1
order by [production order]
```

This way, at least all of the random values will come from the same row, and it will be the row that matches the min end date and time.

Comment: I edited my question. I'm  sorry. I can not get your point. Please specify query for this situation

Answer (score 0):

You can also do as below -

```
Select 
     [Production order],
     min(PN) As PN,
     min(ProjectID) As ProjectID,
     min(Drawing_No) As Drawing_No,
     min(Start_datetime) As Start_datetime,
     max(End_datetime) As End_datetime
from     
(Select [Production order]
      ,FIRST_VALUE([PN]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Production order] ORDER BY Start_datetime) As PN
      ,FIRST_VALUE([ProjectID]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Production order] ORDER BY Start_datetime) As ProjectID
      ,FIRST_VALUE([Drawing No]) OVER (PARTITION BY [Production order] ORDER BY Start_datetime) As Drawing_No
      ,Start_datetime As Start_datetime
      ,End_datetime As End_datetime
from
(select  t.*,
         CAST([start date] as DATETIME) + CAST([start time] as DATETIME) As Start_datetime,
         CAST([end date] as DATETIME) + CAST([end time] as DATETIME) As End_datetime
 from TIMEDATA1 t) Tab ) Tab2
group by 
[Production order];
```

In this method, you simply apply the first_value analytical function on the non-grouping column to get their corresponding value with respect to min start_datetime and then aggregate by grouping column on top of that to get the end output. Assumed date and time fields are string format and hence type casted to datetime. If you fields are already in date and time format you simply need to concat and typecasting would not be required in that case.